# Outer measure must be defined with countably infinite cubes.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Based on the following definition of outer measure of a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$

$$m_*(E) = \inf \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}|Q_j|, \quad \text{where} \  \ E \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{+\infty}Q_j$$

and the $Q_j$ are closed cubes, the author of my text makes the following claim:

> It is important to note that it would not suffice to allow *finite* sums in the definition of $m_*(E)$. The quantity that would be obtained if one considered only coverings of $E$ by finite unions of cubes is in general larger than $m_*(E)$. (See exercise 14.)

This seems intuitive enough (how else could you cover a disk?).

---

> **Exercise 14.** The purpose of this exercise is to show that covering by a finite number of intervals will not suffice in the definition of the outer measure $m_*$.
>
> The outer Jordan content $J_*(E)$ of a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$J_*(E) = \inf \sum_{j=1}^{N} |I_j|$$ where the infimum is taken over every finite covering $E \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^N I_j$ by intervals $I_j$.
>
> (a) Prove that $J_*(E) = J_*(\bar{E})$
>
> (b) Exhibit a countable subset $E\subset [0,1]$ such that $J_*(E) = 1$ while $m_*(E) = 0$.

(a) By noting that $|I_j| = (b_j - a_j) = |\bar{I_j}|$, it's clear that $J_*(E) = J_*(\bar{E})$.

(b) In order to do this, I need to create a subset of $[0,1]$ that has intervals that we can shrink to zero, but where the closure at any step has outer measure of one.

Consider for example the set of rationals $E$ in $[0,1]$. Covered by finite intervals (all contained in $[0,1]$) we have to have $J_*(E) = 1$, because if we didn't that would imply that there was some interval of positive length not covered by the $I_j$, which is impossible since there will be a rational number contained in that interval.

Now, considering coverings of $E$ by infinite intervals, we can choose a countably infinite set of overlapping closed intervals (closed cubes) such that each one is centered around a unique rational number $r \in [0,1]$.
Now, the intersection of the sets in $I$ always covers the entire interval $[0,1]$, because in order to be an interval each $I_j$ must contain an infinite number of rationals. Notice that the size of the intervals was arbitrary. This implies that the infimum of each $|I_j| = 0$.

---

I was having a hard time explicitly constructing this last covering. I'm not sure if that's what the author wanted or if it's a simple formula. I know it's just intervals shrinking around their associated rational. We can make their length a function of $N$, then take $N \to \infty$ but I ran into some confusion writing the interval formulas down.

---

Edit: For clarity, I would like help with this proof. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You could use an enumeration $q_n$ of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, then you can easily write down an interval of small length covering $q_n$.

Comment: @AOrtiz On this site, it's implied that if someone is posting they have a question. For example, an attempted proof might not contain a question mark.

Comment: @Zduff: I understand you have a question. I read your post, but I did not read any particular question. The closest thing to a question was "I was having a hard time..." If you want someone to verify your proof, I would recommend you add the "proof-verification" tag. Otherwise, I would make it more explicit what exactly your question is.

Comment: Question-posts should be explicit, in the body (not only via tags), regarding what is expect from an answer post.

Comment: So, when one presents a solution -- for an *explicit exercise* -- to a group of more knowledgeable peers, it is not clear that they want feedback on the solution? How else could my post be interpreted? I even mention the main part of the proof I'm having an issue with.